# Getting configuration error once try to browse the site inside the default website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, iis

I created asp.net application. then I build that on visual studio and then I added **web.config** file and added following section in that **web.config** file

```
<remotingSetting baseRemoteAddress="http://localhost/application_name/{0}"/>  
<securitySetting accessDeniedUrl="~/Default.aspx"/>
```

then I created a site as **application_name** in Default Website using IIS manager

Then I try to browse this application in IIS manager, I'm getting following configuration error.

[image]

> Configuration Error
>
> **Description:** An error occurred during the processing of a
> configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
> specific error details below and modify your configuration file
> appropriately
>
> **Parser Error Message:** An error occurred loading a configuration file:
>
> Directory 'C:\Users\kelum\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Sample_Project\SampleApp\ConfigSetting' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.
> exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]

.

Comment: You built your project but did you deploy / publish it to IIS?

Comment: no, I haven't published, is there any way to build the project using Visual Studio and then after that run that using IIS manager ?

Comment: Right click the project and publish it to IIS

Comment: Did you have problems with right clicking the project and deploying it? When you _build_ a project, all the source code gets checked and compiled and saved into the _bin_ folder. When you _Deploy_ a porject, it gets built but also gets copied out to your web server. Right now it seems like your web server has no actual deployed code in it, although that is an assumption, it's hard to tell from your comments so far